# Why definition of bounded variable needs us to check values only after certain values?

Tags: calculus

> The variable $x$ is called bounded if there exists a constant $M>0$
>   such that all subsequent values of the variable, $\underline { \text{after a certain one}}$,
>   satisfy the condition  $-M \leq x \leq M$

Why do we need to mention "**values after a certain one**"

Why can't we just say that "if all the values that the variable $x$ can assume are lying between $-M$ and $+M$ (both extremes included), then the variable $x$ is bounded"....?

Again, what about the values before "**a certain one**"?  Aren't they considered while checking if the variable is bounded or not ?

Is it like something like after certain point we don't know the value of $x$ but we can prove that it cannot exceed $M$ ?

**EDIT:**

(1)In the comments below I have mentioned that $x$ is a real number, but in the book just variable is mentioned.

(2) The book is Diff and int calculus Vol I by Piskunov

[image]

Comment: This question is missing context. Is $x$ a real number? A function?

Comment: x is a real number

Comment: If $x$ is a real number, it doesn't mean anything for it to be bounded, because each real number is trivially bounded by itself: $-|x|\leq x\leq |x|$. I think some context is missing.

Comment: @par, same thing can be said if x was any other type of number

Comment: True. My point exactly. Therefore, $x$ is probably not a number in this context. (if every number is bounded, what is the point of making a distinction between bounded and unbounded numbers?)

Comment: Anyways, it sounds like $x$ is really a sequence of numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots$, and boundedness is defined by ignoring the first $N$ terms of the sequence (i.e. $-M \leq x_{N}, x_{N+1}, \ldots \leq M$). In analysis, this is frequently done since one does not care about the first finitely many terms of a sequence (e.g. you can ignore the first finitely many terms when taking limits), but I'm still unsure as to why this is useful in your "mysterious" context.

Comment: Clearly he means a sequence of numbers.

Comment: Are you sure the book doesn't specify boundedness as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist, I have attached the page in my question

Comment: Looks like a pretty confusing book. With that definition $1/x$ is bounded.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist, can you pls come on chat for 5 mins?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist, I have created a room "temp-created-room"